# That technology used in Soundcloud?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

What technology used in Soundcloud that prevents stopping music when you press back button in browser?

I can't find anything about it.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the [History Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), which allows you to manipulate the Browsers history, without forcing a full page-reload.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty cool indeed. I think they load every page with ajax, and then handle the browser history themselves, through javascript. That way you can leave the audio player in the page and load all the rest, achieving the non-stop-music effect